Looking for a Non-Public Provider for BSC Mainnet
I’m currently working on a project that interacts with the Binance Smart Chain (BSC) mainnet, and I’m in need of a non-public provider.
Does anyone have recommendations for non-public BSC mainnet providers that offer better performance, reliability, and support compared to the public ones?
Thanks in advance for your help!

(Disclosure: I'm with Chainstack)
You can also give Chainstack a try. Just log in with eg GitHub you'll be on the free Developer plan. For an upgrade, you can also do the discount coupon listed on the pricing page — that'll give you an upgraded Growth plan at $1.
Depending your preference, you can get a BSC mainnet node running Geth or Erigon.
And last but not least, feel free to message me if there's anything in particular you may need help with as I do developer experience.

You can get the BNB Smart Chain mainnet as well as testnet RPC endpoints (non-public) from QuickNode.


But, in the free plan, you can only get one endpoint with 50 million API credits (i.e., 50 million API calls).

